# Is there .NET wrapper for file bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Is there some wrapper in .NET for file bytes?

I don't like working with byte[]. The type (byte[]) doesn't give enough semantic meaning in case of file bytes because not all byte[] are file bytes. Also passing it as an argument is discomforting...

I know it would be easy to write that kind of wrapper of my own. e.g.:

```
public class FileBytes
{
    public FileBytes
    (
        byte[] value
    )
    {
        Contract.Requires(value != null);
        Contract.Requires(value.Length != 0);

        this.Value = value;
    }

    public byte[] Value { get; private set; }
}
```

But I wonder is there's some out of .NET-box solution.

Comment: as far as I know there isn't (aside from special cases like Images, etc.) - So yeah go on and use your domain knowledge to get some yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing in the BCL. (Or maybe the `Stream` abstraction is what you are looking for?)

Your wrapper has the same problem that a raw `byte[]` has in that variables of type `FileBytes` can be `null`.

Also, I don't see why bytes coming from a file would be any different than bytes coming from somewhere else (e.g. from the web). Code operating on bytes should act the same way no matter where they came from.

Comment: +1 for Stream abstraction; this is often preferred over `byte[]` for File I/O. From the OP's description, a `Stream` more closely matches OP's intention than a `byte[]`.  Most well-designed libraries designed to work with files will have an overload which accepts a `Stream` (and another which accepts a filename).  The main thing to watch out for here is unlike a `byte[]`, a `Stream` has state; it's not inherently safe to reuse a `Stream` (e.g., after you've used a `Stream`, the `Position` property may change).  Similarly, `Stream` is much tougher to safely use in multiple threads.

Comment: @usr I agree that wrapping this should not make any difference for computer or the way a code operates, but I think it does for humans. In my opinion it could make a code little more "honest". :)

Comment: @kr85 nothing wrong with wrapping if you want to document some property in the type system. I just have a hard time seeing the value of documenting that these bytes came from a file as opposed to some other source. If that information is important in your domain, by all means, go for it. I could see this making sense if the bytes have to have some file format, or not zero-length or something like that.